# With clause or subquery factoring clause is giving error for dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to pass the date parameters to with clause and getting below error. If i pass the hardcore values then query retrieving the values.

Query :

```
WITH reg AS
     (  SELECT  'I' AS OPERATION,
        CPIX.ID_VALUE AS ID_VALUE,
        GLOBAL_ID AS GLOBAL_ID,
        DISPLAY_VALUE AS ONEKEY_ID,
        (SELECT  N.NAME FROM NUC_CFG_REGION N WHERE REGION_ID=CPIX.REGION_ID) AS COUNTRY,
         CRTN_DT AS FROM_DATE,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TO_DATE1

    FROM CUS_PRIMARY_ID_XREF CPIX
    WHERE   trunc(crtn_dt)>to_date(&start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') and trunc(crtn_dt)<to_date(&end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
     )
    SELECT Operation,
       country,
       count(onekey_id) Tot_onekey_cnt,
       FROM_DATE,
       TO_DATE1
    from reg
    group by ROLLUP(country),Operation,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE1
    HAVING  (GROUPING(country)=0 )
```

Error :

> ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Comment: What is your date you are using as Input.. It should match with the format mask provided. In your case it should be 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: It has to be  `'&start_date'` (within single quotes)

Comment: Hi Maheswaran,Thanks for your comments. it works!!! Thank you very much for your help.  I missed single quotes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `'&start_date'` (within single quotes)

`&variable` will be simply substituted with the input value, like macros.

Answer (score 0):

The query will work fine unless a proper input date format is provided. In your case the input date must comply with the mask i.e. **'YYYY-MM-DD'.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. If i hardcore the values then it is giving the result for same mask.

Comment: i assume you are trying to get the values dynamically while running in this query.